# Querying XSD-valid XML for the original XML schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Given a schema document (XSD foramt) such as the [MODS 3.5 schema](http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/mods-schemas.html) (US Library of Congress, LoC), and a document (XML) known to be valid according to that schema, such as the [metadata for the Antitrust & Competition Policy Blog archives 2007](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/lcwa/mrva0015.0016/mods.xml) ([HTML view](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/lcwa/mrva0015.0016/default.html)) from the LoC [Law Blawgs Web Archive](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/lcwa/html/lawlb/lawlb-browse.html), is there a Java API such that would allow a Java program to query the XML document for the XML schema data types that elements of the document are instances of?

It may seem as though I have may XML schemas and UML models confused. I'm thinking of an XML schema as it representing something like a UML model (M1), and an XML document then, like *user data* (M0) representing instances of UML model elements. If it may be possible, similarly, to query an XML element, to determine the XML schema data type or element definition that the element either *derives from* or *is conformant to* in the parse tree, I've thought it could make for a nice feature for a sequencer for [ModeShape](http://www.jboss.org/modeshape).

I think, the idea is essentially: That it *may* be possible to reference the JCR nodes representing XML elements of a sequenced XML document, in a ModeShape JCR repository, to reference each element to a JCR node representing an XML schema data type, such the type's representative JCR node would be defined in the sequencing of the schema used by the document, such as would have been sequenced by the ModeShape XSD sequencer.

I'm simply not certain if there may be an API, in Java, for determining the XML schema element than a valid XML document element -- when the XML document is validated according to an XML schema -- such that the element *is conformant to* in the parse tree. I'm of an impression that it would be possible to perform such a computation. Simply, I wonder, might there already be *an API for that?*

Alternately, there is UML...

Comment: Maybe it could be addressed with a validating SAX parser? e.g. _[Implementing SAX Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/validation.html)_ from the Java tutorial

Comment: Another tutorial, introducing the `SchemaFactory` class: _[Java & XML Tutorial: SAX Schema Validation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-schema-validation.html)_

Comment: Thirdly - no closer to associating schema elements with document elements in the parse tree, but it shows  more of the mechanics of schema validation onto SAX: _[Schema Validation using SAX and DOM Parser with Oracle JDeveloper - XDK11g](http://www.packtpub.com/article/schema-validation-sax-dom-parser-with-oracle-jdeveloper)]_

Comment: There's JAXB, alternately - could extend `ValidationEventHandler~? cf. _[Java XML and JSON Binding: JAXB and Marshal/Unmarshal Schema Validation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html)_ - similar to _[Validating Against an XML Schema](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/runtime006.htm)_ from the EclipseLink documentation

Comment: Alternately, there's JDOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142695/validating-xml-with-xsd-using-jdom?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

In terms of standards, validating an XML document against a schema produces a PSVI, (post schema validation infoset), and the PSVI decorates nodes in the parse tree with information about what types they were validated against.

In terms of concrete implementation, if you use the JAXP Validation API you can either generate a DOM augmented with TypeInfo that tells you the type of each node, or you can use a SAX-based validation pipeline in which type information is notified to a TypeInfoProvider.

You can also do this using schema-aware XSLT and XQuery; after a validation operation, nodes are augmented with a "type annotation", which you can interrogate using the "instance of" test. If you use Saxon, you can use the extension functions saxon:type() or saxon:type-annotation() to explore further:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/saxon/type
http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/saxon/type-annotation

A limitation of the XSLT/XQuery approach is that it only works if validation succeeds. The DOM/SAX interfaces also provide information in cases where validation fails.

Comment: Thank you. That's indespensaby helpful. Referencing the [xerces2-j FAQ](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html) I see that Xerces provide access to the PSVI. In regards to my primary _use case_, I think Saxon would be an interesting alternative to ModeShape's XML and XSD sequencers, for generating JCR node type definitions in XML. I think the matter of the PSVI pattern informs the discussion, substantially. I'll focus on the Xerces implementation, initially. The functionality available in XSLT, I'll note for further refence. Thank you!